# Advanced Custom Fields Missing Groups "Add Field"

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm not able to add any field groups in ACF. I've tried increasing PHP memory limits with no luck. Any ideas would be great.

[image]

It's the following section that is missing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your DB, open table usermeta, find your user and delete the field acf_user_settings

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**

I had the same issue and found out it was account-related.
The easiest solution is then to create and use another Wordpress account.

**Database way**

Following @MomasVII answer, the `acf_user_settings` field was not there so I ended up removing all ACF-related field one by one to find the culprit.
Please backup your database if you attempt something like that.

In my case, the issue was resolved after removing the `closedpostboxes_acf-field-group`.